How To Encrypt Data With PEM Public Key In Maui
I am encrypting string data using the following code in .NET 8 platform maui android and using public key in pem format
The PEM Public Key
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAph0TLX18fyIdj5e52yT1
rC1REhkotx5zKCbwMm0lKAjWEFDbDK6weNGBEnlIekS6h8wez7GHr65GckWqLPn0
9XqmMuVkXaBQFLhben+KC/j9Z89QZE4wE7PcOuUqzx8ZvfiTo2d1C89lYFuVS5xe
/RSL8YzqK2TpPm37j0TUXCOv8t4l5T7iZZsye9UxgqYXebBesCnM94GOUvoLvcTh
cRAMnsDKm9uXEh3/jzRZf6s0mUbSaqnoArUZwi+Ndao6h0MNVrH7vFMV4Ierznr9
5RPCMBh3n+rVlYAETU5FpMgRNbDk7s0E7ruX4QSl/WlhXoE75m2JZegzvQAqaCgI
LwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Method 1 : This method is correct, but it works in Windows
 public string EncryptData(string stringToBeEncrypted, string publicKey)
 {
     try
     {
         RsaKeyParameters parameters1 = (RsaKeyParameters)PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey));
         RSAParameters parameters21 = new RSAParameters
         {
             Modulus = parameters1.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned(),
             Exponent = parameters1.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned()
         };
         RSACng cng1 = new RSACng();
         cng1.ImportParameters(parameters21); 
         return Convert.ToBase64String(cng1.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToBeEncrypted), RSAEncryptionPadding.OaepSHA256));
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         return "error";
     }
}

The RSACng Class is only supported on Windows .
And it can't be used in maui android.
Method 2 : I used ECDsa as below, but I get the error again

  public string EncryptData(string stringToBeEncrypted, string publicKey)  
{ 
     try
      {
  var publicKeyBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(publicKey);
  ECParameters parameters2 = new ECParameters
  {
      Curve = System.Security.Cryptography.ECCurve.NamedCurves.nistP256,
      Q = new System.Security.Cryptography.ECPoint
      {
          X = publicKeyBytes.Skip(1).Take(32).ToArray(),
          Y = publicKeyBytes.Skip(33).ToArray()
      },
  };

  ECDsa cng2 = ECDsa.Create();
  cng2.ImportParameters(parameters2);
  return Convert.ToBase64String(cng2.SignData(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(stringToBeEncrypted), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256));

} catch (Exception ex) { return "error"; } } 

Please introduce an alternative to Method 1. That works in Maui android
Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Windows Cryptography Next Generation (CNG) is not supported on this platform.

ECDSA is signing based on elliptic curves and not encryption.

I Thanks for your quick answer. I need emergency !!!

For simple string, you can use  Secure storage to achieve this.

I need to do encryption with the public key received from the site.

Just as Topaco said, the ECDSA is usually used for digital signature generation not encryption. You can encrypt your data in other ways.   You can check this thread first: Encrypting & Decrypting a String in C#.

Please introduce an alternative to Method 1. That works in Maui android.
